# how to go to next index in an array?

Tags: php

I have a search form resulting in search results. Each result has an identity that corresponds to the id in mysql. To get the full result per mysql field, I use a link to fullresult.php?id=569

When retreiving the results, I put all corresponding ids in a $_SESSION['ids'] that looks like this :

```
 array(41) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "569"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "1085"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "289"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "221"
```

When I'm at the page displayed by fullresult.php?id=569, I need to create a link to fullresult.php?id=1085.

Trying to loop trough $_SESSION['ids'], trying to get the current index and going to the next index doesn't seem to work. Or at least i don't see how.

I currently do this :

```
$id_now = $_GET['id'];
$liste_ids = $_SESSION['ids'];
if( ($ida_now = current($liste_ids)) !== FALSE){
    $nxt = next($liste_ids);
    echo$nxt; 
}
```

The problem is that current($liste_ids) always is 569 (first index=>value in $liste_ids) and therefore $nxt always is 1085.

What I'm looking to do when I'm on fullresult.php?id=1085 is to retreive the ** next ** line of $liste_ids so to retreive 289 from $liste_ids and so on.

Comment: So you receive an id via `$_GET` and you want to print a link with the next id in the array, *right* ? Also show your attempts.

Comment: I see 3 things here now. `id`, `ida` and `idas` ?

Comment: Thanks Kishor. Corrected. There should be id and liste_ids only

Answer (score 1):

```
// Make sure the session is started
if(!session_id())
    session_start();

// Make sure the user entered the id on the URL
if(empty($_GET["id"]))
    die("Please enter the id of the result");

$resultId = $_GET["id"];

// Validate the id
if(!is_numeric($resultId))
    die("Invalid id, it most be an integer");

if(empty($_SESSION["ids"]))
    die("No ids to follow");

// First the index of the $resultId
$resultIndex = array_search($resultId, $_SESSION["ids"]);

if($resultIndex === false)
    die("Couldn't find ". $resultId);

$resultIndex++;

if(empty($_SESSION["ids"][$resultIndex]))
    die("Reached end");
else
    echo "Your link is " . "/fullresult.php?id=" . $_SESSION["ids"][$resultIndex];
```

Comment: in this example, $resultIndex is the current index. I'm looking for the next value...

Comment: Just change it to `$_SESSION['ids'][$resultIndex+1]` and it should work. Also, some validating if the key exists would be cool.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as long as,

- You have an unique array.
- you get a value in the array from the `GET` parameter
- you array has all indexes.

It can be made much more easier if you are sure there are all array indexes present. Then it would be,

```
$needle = $_GET['id']; //id in your url has value, not index.
$index = array_search('$needle', $array);//get the index.
$value = $array($index+1);
echo $value;
```

On a general note, when all array indexes are present, this may be used.

```
$needle = $_GET['id']; 
$index = array_search('$needle', $array);
while (key($List) !== $index){ 
$value = next($index);
}
echo $value;
```

Please test the code as I havent tested it. Also, take any defensive steps necessary. Like the user manually changing the url to a value that is not in the array. And so on.